# image + link as a field in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I need a folder image with a link to the corresponding folder like,

```
            HyperLink fileLink = new HyperLink();
            fileLink.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/OPENFOLD.GIF";
            fileLink.NavigateUrl = url_string;
```

The url string was constructed based on other column values in the same row. How to add this image + link field to each row of a grid view?
I dont think a custom field is an option here...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at templating a gridview.

Using templates you can specify that a specific row contains an image with a hyperlink on it, binding the NavigateURL property to a specific value. This can occur for each row.

This is a good tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx

Comment: I am creating the data table that needs to be bound to the grid dynamically,and the data is from an xml document. This is similar to a search page...

Comment: ok... so templates do sound like they would be useful then? i think you should give them a go and you will possibly realise that they will do what you want